# How to POST images from chrome extension to Google Drive using Google Apps Script WebApp and JQuery

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension, file-upload, blob

I have a Google Chrome extension that I require to generate an image/png type image when I press CTRL + V (This works OK). After that I require to send this image to Google Drive using a Google Apps Script web application. But I have not been able to figure out how to do this. I am using ajax with jQuery

This is the code I have used to capture and create the image and works fine

```
$(partial).on('paste', e => { // partial is an dynamic html
    e = e.originalEvent
    let item = Array.from(e.clipboardData.items).find(x => /^image\//.test(x.type))
    let blob = item.getAsFile()
    let base = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    let img = new Image()
    img.src = base
    img.onload = function () {
        let w = this.width
        let h = this.height
        $(partial).find('.img-evi').attr('width', w)
        $(partial).find('.img-evi').attr('height', h)
        $(partial).find('.img-evi').attr('src', base) // show the image paste in screen

        let reader = new FileReader() // try to send the image to Google Drive
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            const file = new File([blob], "capture.png", {
                type: 'image/png'
            })
            var fd = new FormData()
            fd.append("image", file)
            $.ajax({ // Call Google Apps Script WebApp by POST
                type: "POST",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/#########/exec",
                data: fd,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                success: (data) => {
                    alert("yes");
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }
    img.remove()
})
```

In apps script i have that

```
function doPost(e) {
  let FOLDER = DriveApp.getFolderById('### Folder ID ######')
  let imgBlob = Utilities.newBlob(e.postData, 'image/png', "### how to get name ? ###")
  let fileId = FOLDER.createFile(imgBlob).getId()
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
    ok: true,
    data: { id: fileId },
    title: 'Success',
    message: `The image id is ${fileId}.`
  })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there a error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `file` is Blob. I think that this cannot be directly used for sending to Web Apps.
- In this modification, the data is converted to the int8array and is sent it to Web Apps as the string value.
- By this, it is required to modify your Google Apps Script side.

When these points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Javascript side:

##### From:

```js
let reader = new FileReader() // try to send the image to Google Drive
reader.onload = function (e) {
    const file = new File([blob], "capture.png", {
        type: 'image/png'
    })
    var fd = new FormData()
    fd.append("image", file)
    $.ajax({ // Call Google Apps Script WebApp by POST
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/#########/exec",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: (data) => {
            alert("yes");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

##### To:

```js
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
  const values = { data: [...new Int8Array(e.target.result)], filename: "capture.png", mimeType: "image/png" };
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(values),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    success: (data) => {
      console.log(data)
      alert("yes");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
function doPost(e) {
  const { data, filename, mimeType } = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  let FOLDER = DriveApp.getFolderById('### Folder ID ######');
  let imgBlob = Utilities.newBlob(data, mimeType, filename);
  let fileId = FOLDER.createFile(imgBlob).getId();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
    ok: true,
    data: { id: fileId },
    title: 'Success',
    message: `The image id is ${fileId}.`
  })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
}
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Your answer was pretty perfect, just to complement ... is there a way to put an upload progress? i have tried to put it with `xhr:` but i get CORS error 405 error jQuery v3.6.0

Comment: @Jailer Betancourt Thank you for replying. About your new question, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: i posted a new question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71687107/how-to-show-the-file-upload-progress-in-jquery-ajax-post-to-google-apps-script-w  thank you